# How to Create Subdomains with CakePHP?

Tags: php, website, domain, subdomain

Does anyone know how to create a subdomain with cakephp? For example:

www.domain.com/subdomainname like this without any additional characters attached to the subdomainname.

Answer (score 1):

A subdomain is like this: subdomain.domain.com
You can't do that with CapePHP, you will have to configure your web server with something like cPanel
If you mean www.domain.com/view/12 instead of www.domain.com/view.php?id=12  that is called mod rewriting and is done with a combination of webserver configuration and setting up a routes.php file in CakePHP